# FileNotFoundError with flutter_dotenv

Tags: flutter, dotenv

I installed flutter_dotenv with this command:

```
flutter pub add flutter_dotenv
```

My is pubspec.yaml is like:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.0

flutter:
assets:
    - .env
```

Then I put .env file in the project root (I will use .env.dev. .env.prd later so you see them in the screen shot):

[image]

I run project from VSCode then get FileNotFoundError:
[image]

I checked the .env file location hundred of times, tried to change the file name, change the location to /lib etc - still no luck. Any idea?

Answer (score 30):

I found what was wrong. "assets:" must be under "flutter:", so tab is necessary before "assets:". That's it!

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - .env
```

Comment: Mine looks like this but still I'm getting the error

Answer (score 2):

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - .env
```

It's working for me.